# write panda data to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, csv

I have a csv sheet and it looks like below , each column has  some data.
Want to filter data by Name . I know the names, from which I have to filter.

```
Name  gender  address  age  post  city 
A      M       abc     20   dd     ASD
C      F       xyz     21   ll     KLM
B      M       lmn     22   mm     NOP
```

Want output like.

```
Name    address     post   city 
A         abc        dd     ASD
B         lmn        mm     NOP
```

The code below obviously overwrite the first data in csv. How to avoid that and fix this. Also, want to get rid of index column from excel. Any better way to code this ? New to Panda here .

```
for i in ['A','B']: #The names list is huge , taking 2 as example
        df=pd.read_csv('some.xlsx',index_col=False)
        df1= df.loc[df['Name'] == i, ['Name','address','post','city']]
df1.to_csv('ABC.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **[isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)**:

**Ex:**

```
df=pd.read_csv('some.xlsx',index_col=False)
df1 = df.loc[df['Name'].isin(['A','B']), ['Name','address','post','city']]
df1.to_csv('ABC.csv')
```

- Pass your list as input to `isin`

*Edit as per comment - Using a loop*

```
df1 = None
for i in ['A','B']:
    if df1 is not None:
        df1 = df1.append( df.loc[df['Name'] == i, ['Name','address','post','city']] )
    else:
        df1 =  df.loc[df['Name'] == i, ['Name','address','post','city']]

df1.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: Thank You . It works. My problem is bit more than that ...I have to loop through the list available as need to perform some operation in between and directly can not pass the list using .isin . Is there any way while using `loop` the data can be append in csv without overwriting it  ? Also , still I am having `index` column in csv.Want to get rid of that.

Comment: df1 can be empty for some `Name` , i need to go through loop to check that as well. Thats why want to avoid `isin` . I want to append the new data to existing csv .

Comment: I'll test it and will reply in sometime. Thank for you time and effort.

Comment: It served my purpose nearby. Did some modification to use as per my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) is the function you need. It returns a boolean Series which can be used to filter the DataFrame when used as its index. For multiple names, separate the names with `|` (pipe symbol).

```
names_list = ['A', 'B']
my_names = '|'.join(names_list)  # my_names = "A|B"
df = pd.read_csv('some.xlsx', index_col=False)
df1 = df1[df["Name"].str.contains(my_names)]
df1 = df1[['Name', 'address', 'post', 'city']]    
df1.to_csv("filtered.csv")
```

Comment: This solution should be modified. It will display all the column names unnecessary(without contents)along with the one we want.

Comment: @steveJ Thanks for pointing out! I have updated my answer for the required column names :)